# How to use a function in three different .cpp files

Tags: c++, c, include, directx

I have three **.cpp** files these are named **MeshLoader.cpp**, **DynamicXMesh.cpp** and **StaticXMesh.cpp**

I have a function in the **MeshLoader.cpp** file named **FindTexturePath** and I want to call and use it in the **DynamicXMesh.cpp** and **StaticXMesh.cpp** files.

I have included **MeshLoader.cpp**(#include "MeshLoader.cpp") file in boot **XMesh** files and of course get an error that says function is already defined...

Also I tryed to use **pragma once** and **ifndef** ...:

```
//This is "MeshLoader.cpp"
pragma once

#ifndef MLOAD
#define MLOAD
  char* FindTexturePath( char* TexturePath ,LPSTR FileNameToCombine){
      ...
      ...
      ...
  }
#endif
```

/////

```
//This is StaticXMesh.cpp
#include "MeshLoader.cpp"
...
...
...
this->StatXMeshTexturePath = FindTexturePath(StatXMeshTexturePath,d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename);
...
...
```

/////
And same call for DynamicXMesh.cpp

I hope I explained myself clear enough... Thank you for givin your time...

Comment: I would recommend you reading a book about C++. Any will do.

Comment: You got some good answers but I feel like it's always important to know _why_ as well. Check out this [overview of compiling and linking](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/book/compiling.html). It might be a bit obtuse at first but it really is useful for C programming.

Comment: Thank you for that documentation it realy looks like usefull for me I'll read it for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create MeshLoader.h, and put something like this in it

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_MESH_LOADER_H
#define INCLUDED_MESH_LOADER_H

char* FindTexturePath( char* TexturePath ,LPSTR FileNameToCombine);

#endif
```

And include that in your other cpp files.  Each of the cpp files just need the declaration of FindTexturePath to compile.  So whenever you need to make a function in a cpp public to other cpp files, create a .h file that has the function declarations in.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred method is to put the function declaration in a .h file, and let the linker combine all the .cpp files into one executable.

If you insist on doing it in a nonstandard way, you can make what you have work by making the function `inline` or `static`.

Answer (score 1):

put the function prototype in an header file (MeshLoader.h) and include that file everywhere you need to use that function.

Answer (score 1):

As other users have stated, you want to place **declarations** into the header (`.h` or `.hpp`) file.

At times you may wish to have a **definition** in the header file as well. At this point, you make a static function definition: `static char* FindTexturePath(...) { .. }`